# VBA Outlook How to add hyperlink into email body

Tags: vba, winapi, outlook

This macro adds hyperlink to email :

```
  Sub test_add_hyperlink()
     Dim NewMail As Outlook.MailItem
     Set NewMail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
     NewMail.HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY><A href=http://www.someaddress.com>URL_TEXT</A></BODY></HTML>" & NewMail.HTMLBody  End Sub
```

but how to add hyperlink in place where active cursor is ? I ask beacause I would like to add hyperlink not at the front of message, but where my currently writing message.

The hyperlink I would like to add is the hyperlink to file which is currently copied to Windows' clipboard, this part I've written, but I can't figure out how to place it not at the front of email, but in place where active cursor is. I think that macro based emulation of Windows' keypressing is one of the directions to follow.

Answer (score 2):

This describes how to paste at the selection.

http://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/paste-formatted-text-vba/

```
Sub PasteFormattedClipboard()

    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objInsp As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim objSel As Word.Selection

    Set objItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Set objInsp = objItem.GetInspector
    Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor
    Set objWord = objDoc.Application
    Set objSel = objWord.Selection

    objSel.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objInsp = Nothing
    Set objDoc = Nothing
    Set objWord = Nothing
    Set objSel = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub InsertHyperlinkAtCursorPositon()
On Error GoTo finish
strLink = "http://www.outlookcode.com"
strLinkText = "Get Outlook code samples here"
Set objInsp = Application.ActiveInspector
Set objMsg = objInsp.CurrentItem
Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor
Set objSel = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection
If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatPlain Then
    objDoc.Hyperlinks.Add objSel.Range, strLink, _
                          "", "", strLinkText, ""
Else
    objSel.InsertAfter strLink
End If
finish:
End Sub
```