# Sending a filepath hyperlink in Gmail using VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel, gmail

I am doing an approval route which will auto generate an email to the user when there is a new entry. Everything works extremely cool till I try to insert a hyperlink to the workbook in the sent email. FYI, I am using Gmail.

This is my code:

```
With NewMail
    .Subject = RequestSubmission.ComboBox1.Text & ":pending your approval"
    .From = "****@gmail.com"
    .To = "****@gmail.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .HTMLBody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
              "To whom it may concern,<br><br>" & _
              "There is a new request:<br><B>" & _
              RequestSubmission.ComboBox1.Text & "</B> is created.<br>" & _
              "Click on this link to approve or reject the request : " & _
              "<A HREF=""file:///\\shared123\home20\user\Profile\Desktop\dailyreport.xls"">Approval or Rejection</A>" & _
              "<br><br>Regards," & _
              "<br><br>Max</font>"
    .AddAttachment RequestSubmission.TextBox2.Text
End With
```

I believe I missed out something in the HTML body but I could not find it and rectify it. Someone help me please...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29776811/6591278 ?

Comment: I tried with the outlook vba code but it does not work with gmail sadly :(

Comment: Is `local_filepath` a variable or just a placeholder for the real path? If it is a variable you should use something like `"<A HREF=""" & local_filepath & """>Approval or Rejection</A>"`

Comment: Sorry I should mention it in the post. It is just a placeholder for the real path :)

Comment: Then I have to ask what your issue is. What does not work and what happens instead of what you expected? How does your local file path look like (you can change folder names but keep the main structure!). It should look like `file:///C:/temp/`

Comment: Hi! I have just edited the code with the file path with the file:/// in front of the path. It does not work. I am using shared drive (network drive). Is it possible that there are restriction with the shared drive?

Comment: Well, I think it should be `file://shared123/home20/user/Profile/Desktop/dailyreport.xls`. Note that `\ ` in the path gets converted to `/`.