Including a hyperlink in email body
I create an email containing:

To: email addresses stored in tab "info" range M2 until empty line

CC: hardcoded email address

Subject: Overview - 'Dateoftoday'

Body:
Dear all,
Please find below overview of today.
Click this link to open the file
Screenshot of sheet "Status" range B2:W62
Signature setup in the user's email


The word 'Link' should hyperlink to the current workbook path.
I don't want the email to automatically send. I'd like the end users to be able to check everything first.
I cannot get a hyperlink in this code.
Sub Mail()
If ActiveSheet.Name \<\> "Status" Then
    MsgBox "This macro can only be executed from the Status sheet!"
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim Ol As Object 'Outlook.Application
Dim Olemail As Object 'Outlook.MailItem
Dim Olinsp As Object 'Outlook.Inspector
Dim Wd As Object 'Word.Document
Dim Maillist As String
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
Dim LastMember As Long
LastMember = Worksheets("Info").Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Row
    
For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Info").Range("M2:M" &LastMember).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If cell.Value Like "*" Then
        Maillist = Maillist & ";" & cell.Value
    End If
Next

Set Ol = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") '/\* if outlook is running, create otherwise \*/
Set Olemail = Ol.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem

With Olemail

    .To = Maillist

    ' .CC = "HARCODED EMAIL"

    Set Olinsp = .GetInspector
    If Olinsp.EditorType = 4 Then 'olEditorWord
        Set Wd = Olinsp.WordEditor
    End If
    
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Status" Then
        Wd.Paragraphs(1).Range.InsertBefore "Dear all," & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Please find below overview of today." & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
        
        Sheets("Status").Range("B2:W62").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        
        .Subject = "Overview - " & Date
    End If

    Wd.Paragraphs.Add
    '    wd.Paragraphs(4).Range.Characters.Last.PasteAndFormat 13 & Chr(13) & Chr(13)
    Wd.Paragraphs(4).Range.Characters.Last.PasteAndFormat 13

    With Wd
        .InlineShapes(1).Height = 800
    End With
    
    .Display

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25628116/4717755

In the '.body' you can reference a cell that has the hyperlink you want the email to include.
